# Dart Web_Audio for Dart 1.6

Tags: dart, web-audio-api

I've been researching how to play a .wav file in dart and have been able to do it successfully via the AudioElement defined in the dart:html library. However, I am interested in using the dart:web_audio library and have come across all of these different ways to do it:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/13471195250/web-audio-api-how-to-playing-audio-based-on-user

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/blob/master/html5/web/webaudio/intro/filter_sample.dart#L1

http://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/web-audio-api-and-dart.html

Unfortunately none of these are suiting my need nor do they work. I feel like because all of them are a few years old, I am missing something for Dart 1.6. Any ideas?

Comment: Some more details what your specific needs are?

Comment: Please add code and the errors that you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

The main recent significant changes from some examples you gave are

- noteOn replaced by start
- for many API, the Node suffix has been removed: audioContext.createGain() (was createGainNode)
- ...and sometimes the Audio prefix was removed: GainNode (was AudioGainNode)
- usage of decodeAudioData for decoding ogg/mp3 from an incoming raw buffer

WebAudio is still a Working Draft (http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) and chrome tends to follow the newest API

I have a very simple audio example working (as of dart 1.6) here: https://github.com/alextekartik/dart-test/tree/master/audio_test